# Ignoring a missing file in a for loop- Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am going through some files and dividing their values in my code. The for-loop is there to parse through the many iterations of the file-type (it's just much quicker). However, sometimes, a file might not exist. How do I just skip over that and let the for-loop continue, because certain file numbers might not exist for a reason.

Code:

```
import pyfits as pf

for i in range (1,18):
   img1= pf.getdata("galmasksciPHOTOf105w"+str(i)+".fits")
   img2= pf.getdata("fittedsciPHOTOf105w"+str(i)+".fits")
   img3=(img2)[2]
   newimg=img1/img3
   pf.writeto("dividedsciPHOTOf105w"+str(i)+".fits",newimg, clobber=True)

for i in range (1,18):
   img1= pf.getdata("galmasksciPHOTOf125w"+str(i)+".fits")
   img2= pf.getdata("fittedsciPHOTOf125w"+str(i)+".fits")
   img3=(img2)[2]
   newimg=img1/img3
   pf.writeto("dividedsciPHOTOf125w"+str(i)+".fits",newimg, clobber=True)

for i in range (1,22):
   img1= pf.getdata("galmasksciPHOTOf140w"+str(i)+".fits")
   img2= pf.getdata("fittedsciPHOTOf140w"+str(i)+".fits")
   img3=(img2)[2]
   newimg=img1/img3
   pf.writeto("dividedsciPHOTOf140w"+str(i)+".fits",newimg, clobber=True)

for i in range (1,22):
   img1= pf.getdata("galmasksciPHOTOf160w"+str(i)+".fits")
   img2= pf.getdata("fittedsciPHOTOf160w"+str(i)+".fits")
   img3=(img2)[2]
   newimg=img1/img3
   pf.writeto("dividedsciPHOTOf160w"+str(i)+".fits",newimg, clobber=True)
```

So, for example, fittedsciPHOTOf125w4 does not exist, and Python stops the code there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `os.path.exists` or `os.path.isfile` to test whether the file exists or not first. Or put your reading statements in a `try...except: pass` block.

```
for i in range (1,18):
   if os.path.isfile("galmasksciPHOTOf105w"+str(i)+".fits") and os.path.exists("fittedsciPHOTOf105w"+str(i)+".fits"):
       img1= pf.getdata("galmasksciPHOTOf105w"+str(i)+".fits")
       img2= pf.getdata("fittedsciPHOTOf105w"+str(i)+".fits")
       img3=(img2)[2]
       newimg=img1/img3
       pf.writeto("dividedsciPHOTOf105w"+str(i)+".fits",newimg, clobber=True)
```

OR:

```
for i in range (1,18):
   try:
       img1= pf.getdata("galmasksciPHOTOf105w"+str(i)+".fits")
       img2= pf.getdata("fittedsciPHOTOf105w"+str(i)+".fits")
       img3=(img2)[2]
       newimg=img1/img3
       pf.writeto("dividedsciPHOTOf105w"+str(i)+".fits",newimg, clobber=True)
   except IOError:
       pass
```

Comment: Generally speaking, which approach is faster? Anyone know off-hand?

Comment: It depends. If your missing file is rare the second is faster. If it is often, I think the first one is better.

Comment: The first one producues a race condition: if the file is removed in the small time range between checking and opening the file, you get an error as well. Besides, other IO errors can happen as well, so you should use `try:`/ `except:` in any case (and maybe print the error as well).

Answer (score 2):

I would like to write this as a comment, but alas, that doesn't work in this extent.

You should try to avoid code repetition:

```
import pyfits as pf

def process_file(filenamebase)
    img1 = pf.getdata("galmask" + filenamebase)
    img2 = pf.getdata("fitted" + filenamebase)
    img3 = img2[2]
    newimg = img1/img3
    pf.writeto("divided" + filenamebase, newimg, clobber=True)

for i in range (1,18):
    process_file("PHOTOf105w" + str(i) + ".fits")
    # or
    process_file("PHOTOf105w%d.fits" % i)
    # or
    process_file("PHOTOf105w{0}.fits".format(i))

for i in range (1,18):
    process_file("PHOTOf125w{0}.fits".format(i))

for i in range (1,22):
    process_file("PHOTOf140w{0}.fits".format(i))

for i in range (1,22):
    process_file("PHOTOf160w{0}.fits".format(i))
```

And now you can apply [zhangyangyu's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17825090/296974):

```
def process_file(filenamebase)
    import sys # for stderr
    try:
        img1 = pf.getdata("galmask" + filenamebase)
        img2 = pf.getdata("fitted" + filenamebase)
        img3 = img2[2]
        newimg = img1/img3
        pf.writeto("divided" + filenamebase, newimg, clobber=True)
    except IOError, e:
        print >>sys.stderr, e # in order to know what happened.
```

and you have this one change in all 4 loops at once.